# Quill JS – set line height on Quill's size classes on span elements without inline-block

Tags: css, quill

I'm in an environment where Quill is needed as a WYSIWYG editor.

I've added 'sizes' to the toolbar to have small, normal and large text.

Quill uses classes to set the font size, however, it adds the class to a `<span>` inside of the element the text is in, such as a `<p>`, such that setting text to small will yield the following HTML:

```
<p>This <span class="ql-size-small">is a</span> test</p>
```

The above works fine for when only part of the copy has its font size adjusted.

However, the problem comes when I set the entire paragraph to a size in Quill. Which results in the following HTML:

```
<p><span class="ql-size-small">This is a test</span></p>
```

Because now, the line-height of the parent `<p>` tag is used, which creates huge gaps between lines and paragraphs as a result, like this:

[image]

And because the `<span>` is `display: inline` I can't set a `line-height` on it.

So, I go an put `display: inline-block` on the element.. but then this causes TWO other issues, first:

[image]

Second... let's suppose you want to have a paragraph like the following, where the first line is bold AND there is a `<br />` (using Shift+Enter) after the first line:

[image]

But... now I set a size in Quill for this whole paragraph, and now it looks like this (!):

[image]

It looks like this because we had to add `display: inline-block` to the `.ql-size-small` class, AND because Quill puts the `<br />` (from the Shift+Enter) on the INSIDE of the `<span>` element, so that the HTML looks like this:

```html
<p>
    <strong style="color: rgb(110, 110, 110);" class="ql-size-small">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit met
    </strong>
    <span style="color: rgb(110, 110, 110);" class="ql-size-small">
        <br>
        This is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test.&nbsp;This is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test.
    </span>
</p>
```

Now, with this second one, if Quill had put the `<br />` on the OUTSIDE (in-between the `<strong>` and the `<span>` elements, this wouldn't be a problem. But because we had to put `display: inline-block` on the `.ql-size-small` class so that `line-height` would work, the `<br />` creates a blank line.

---

I'm not sure what to do about this, it seems that there isn't a solution to this that allows me to have:

- Sizes
- Shift+Enter for newline
- Configurable line-height for small text without `inline-block`
- No big gaps

Now, I could abuse the `<h5>` and `<h6>` and have them reversed for case/page-specific styling where I need a bold line of text with no margin-bottom, but it feels I shouldn't need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Editing the css file that comes with Quill.

Modify the line height for the class .ql-editor

```
.ql-editor {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  **line-height: 1.42;**
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  tab-size: 4;
  -moz-tab-size: 4;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

and add if you want to add some space between each paragraph tag, add this to the end of the CSS file

```
.ql-editor p {
  margin-bottom:25px !important
}
```

Obviously, modify the as needed